# How can I connect multiple forms to one button

Tags: php, html

i was trying to make a simple process for a page but could not be sure for a part, can someone show how i can take all these multiple form values with the second form submit button only to send it to database ?

the code:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
                    <select name="yrank" onchange="yRankFunc()" id="yrank" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                        <option value="select" selected="selected" >Select</option>
                        <option value="iron">Iron</option>
                        <option value="bronze">Bronze</option>
                        <option value="silver">Silver</option>
                        <option value="gold">Gold</option>
                        <option value="platinum">Platinum</option>
                        <option value="diamond">Diamond</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="yrankno" onchange="yRankNoFunc()" id="yRankNo" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                        <option value="select" selected="selected" >Select</option>
                        <option value="4">IV</option>
                        <option value="3">III</option>
                        <option value="2">II</option>
                        <option value="1">I</option>
                    </select>
                </form>


 <form style="margin-top:30px;" method="post" action="process.php">
                    <label name="lolname" style="color:rgb(66,220,163);"><b>LoL Display Name</b></label> <br> <input style="outline:none;" type="text"> </input> <br><br>
                    <label name="discordname" style="color:rgb(66,220,163);"><b>Discord Name</b></label> <br> <input placeholder="username#????" style="outline:none;" type="text"> </input>
                    <br><br> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-default" type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                </form>


<form method="post" action="process.php">
                    <select name="nrank" onchange="nRankFunc()" id="nrank" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                        <option value="select" selected="selected" >Select</option>
                        <option id="b" value="bronze">Bronze</option>
                        <option id="s" value="silver">Silver</option>
                        <option id="g" value="gold">Gold</option>
                        <option id="p" value="platinum">Platinum</option>
                        <option id="d" value="diamond">Diamond</option>
                        <option value="master">Master</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="nrankno" onchange="nRankNoFunc()" id="nRankNo" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                        <option value="select" selected="selected" >Select</option>
                        <option value="4">IV</option>
                        <option value="3">III</option>
                        <option value="2">II</option>
                        <option value="1">I</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
```

Comment: You can't do that (unless you involve Javascript). But, if you need to submit all of this data together, then why have you separated it into multiple forms? Logically, this should all be one form.

Comment: @El_Vanja it's not the complete code, i did that because they are in different columns, thought it might not make sense to involve the column divs,some text into the form as well

Comment: It doesn't really matter where they are positioned on the page. There should be only one form tag and you can position the inputs inside it however you want to.

Comment: @El_Vanja oh, i thought including the other elements that is not related wouldnt make sense. Well, since it does not matter, i can just do that. Thanks... Gonna try and post as an answer if it works if there are other people thinking the same like i was.

Comment: You can use form submission by jquery ajax. When you click the "single" button, it show trigger the ajax submission of the forms one by one. But @El_Vanja is right that you can just submit all the data in one form, and then the target PHP to separately process the three sets of data at the server side.